# Does Spring jpa pessimistic/optimistic locking on row apply to other applications accessing the table row

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, persistence, spring-transactions

I have appA doing a table access with write lock on a row.
While it is holding the lock,

Would another appB deployed on another server be able to update the same row.
OR
My sql client (say sqlYog)  be able to update the row manually

My question is to understand whether the persistence manager be able to prevent other manual or programmatic updates from other applications that are not within the same application context which holds the lock.

Answer (score 1):

From a database perspective it doesn't matter who tries to update the data. It could be another application or even another thread in your first application instance.

If you did an optimistic lock on a row then this row can be modified by anyone because optimistic lock doesn't prevent concurrent modifications.

> Optimistic locking is a technique for SQL database applications that does not hold row locks between selecting and updating or deleting a row. The application is written to optimistically assume that unlocked rows are unlikely to change before the update or delete operation.

via: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=overview-optimistic-locking

On the contrary, a pessimistic locking mechanism involves locking entities on the database level. If you do a pessimistic lock on a given row then no one (another app instance, database client managed manually by you etc.) else would be able to modify data in that row.